# I want to create a radio button in angular 6 forms using only one input field

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, angular6, radio-group

I want to create a radio button in angular 6 forms using only one input field - here my problem is my input field is inside a ngFor loop which extracts the value from an array. Now i want to create a radio button for gender so any suggestions or references how can i do it ? 
Here is my code -

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (submit)="submit(myGroup.value)">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let info of myGroup.controls['myInfo'].controls; let i = index">

            <label for="{{labelValue[i].name}}"> {{labelValue[i].label}}
            <input type="{{labelValue[i].type}}" value="{{labelValue[i].value}}" class="{{labelValue[i].class}}" [formControl]="info">
          </label>

      </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
  <button class="form-control btn-sub" type=”submit”>
    Submit Details
  </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my array in component.ts file from where it takes the values -

```
public labelValue: InputType[] = [
  {name:"fname",type:"text",label:"First Name", class:"form-control",value:"Sheili"},
  //{name:"lname",type:"text",label:"Last Name", class:"form-control"},
  {name:"ctype",type:"text",label:"Customer Type", class:"form-control",value:"INDIVIDUAL"},
  {name:"dob",type:"date",label:"Date Of Birth", class:"form-control",value:"1985-11-17"},
  {name:"gender",type:"text",label:"Gender",class:"form-control",value:"Female"},
  {name:"email",type:"email", label:"E-mail", class:"form-control",value:"Sheili@gmail.com"},
];
```

Comment: What's the error by the way ?

Comment: generally for a radio button we need two or more input fields with the same name but here i want to create 2 radio buttons using only one input field as it is inside a for loop. so if you can suggest me anything?

Comment: you have 2 types of form field here, input and radio button, you can make both in your template and with *ngif select which one to use, input or radio button.

Comment: can you please tell me how if possible cos im way too confused.

Comment: i am not sure , if i got you right and you are expecting your ngFor loop to run twice and generate two radio buttons on your UI ?

Comment: see i want to produce 2 radio buttons only through this input field which is shown in the code. means I want to create 2 radio buttons only with a single input field. it is bcos the input field is inside a ngFor loop. and i have 2 types of inputs one is text and the other is radio.

Comment: You have to update your type as radio, then add the values in your array {name:"gender",type:"radio",label:"Gender",class:"form-control",value:"Female"},

Comment: ya i tried doing that but i need 2 radio buttons for male and female by using just one input field.

Comment: https://angular-xsbudb.stackblitz.io/ 

can you please have a look and let me know if that is what you are expecting ?

Comment: this link is not running.. console is giving an error window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage'

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsbudb

check this

Comment: @faizan you added 2 different gender items to InputType and it's not correct, we get one item named gender.

Comment: yes actually the solution will disturb my design.

Comment: yes and you can't change your input data from server or ... , but my solution is correct  and works with one gender item specially in form group you won't have problem for binding data. check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duacq6)

Comment: ah.. that's upto you how you want to hide one gender label , my motive was to give an idea to her that she can actually add the object in array, then we can generate input field on UI

Comment: I dont have only 2 input types i have multiple input types including date., number, email, password etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 types of form field here, input and radio button, you can make both in your template and with *ngif select which one to use, text or radio button.
for e.g in your for loop:

```
        <div *ngIf="type === 'text'" formGroupName="userData">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" 
             id="email" formControlName = "email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div  *ngIf="type === 'radio'" class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" [value]="gender"
            formControlName = "gender">{{gender}}
          </label>
       </div>
```

ts code:

```
 genders=['male','female'];
```

Comment: but she is already passing type as well from component through labelValue property , she just needs to have two radio button [only one to select at a time],

I think by adding objects to labelValue array , which will have same name but different values , both having type as radio, her scenario can be achieved.

Comment: yep, i covered it in that stackBlitz example, if you are not behind any proxy server , you should be able to see the code as well as the outcome